# Python C Extending callback functions

Tags: python, c, binding, callback

I am trying to write a binding to a C-Library that uses callback functions.

A function interface may look like:

```
int do_something(int a, void (*callback));
```

And i want to map it the same way in python so someone can write:

```
def callback(val):
    print val

do_something(1, callback)
```

So the Python call `do_something` should call the C-Function `do_something`. And the Python function `callback` should be connected to the C-Functions `callback`.

How should I approach this?

Very thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `C` syntax for the callback function pointer is incorrect.  Should be: `void (*callback)(int)`.

Comment: Ok, thats correct. I am using -fpermissive flag since the library i want to link to requires this...

Comment: I'm not sure if it should even be declared as a C function pointer; there might be some "python function pointer" type instead.

Comment: Well, what i get is a PyObject* which can be called by PyObject_CallObject but this is nothing i can pass to the C-Function do_something which expects a C callback :-(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach should be defining, for each C function, a Python Wrapper, and using them. As a C function cannot be directly a Python Callable, this is a nice way of packing it.

Another approach should be defining your own class in the C extension which includes the method **call**. Through this C Python function, you can manage whatever you want and perform the connection to C function callbacks. The object becomes the generic callback, or subclass, or...

If you want to keep everything on the C level, then use Python Capsules to pass around the C function pointers. But then the callback is at a C level and not at a Python level.

To be more precise, you need to give further information of type of callbacks, quantity, variety, domain, etc. I cannot think of a universal way of achieving your goal, but I can imagine a variety of scenarios and implementations.